# How to Solve Syntax Error, Adding Firebase to React Project

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

[image]

My react app loads fine locally with nodemon. However, when I try to add Firebase, html in index.html renders, but none of my react app gets rendered. Additionally, I get error codes about unexpected token '<'. Exact Error Code:   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. My research indicates this has something to do with passing HTML instead of JS, but I'm not sure where I'm doing that?

My firebase.json file (most stack overflow results seem to point to errors here, but I haven't been able to solve)

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Below, my h1 'Hi' gets rendered, but none of my react app loads in div id=root.

[image]

Comment: Try to open the link in private mode, or **Browse as Guest** and see if it gone